# Tag Property in WPF DataGrid Column

Tags: wpf, datagrid, tags, datagridcolumn

I need to save an string inside a Datagrid Column which differs from the Header.

This is needed because I generate a Datagrid dynamically and want to translate the Column Headers while generating them. Then I bind the whole XAML to a ContentControl.

No problem till here... But I want to reorder and resize the columns, so I need to lookup them afterwoods. For this I need the original (not translated) ColumnHeader.

In my opinion a Tag property of the column would solve this problem, but there is no :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In WPF, you have virtually unlimited "Tag" properties by using [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx). An attached property can be set on any `DependencyObject`. A good example of such an attached property is `Grid.Row`. Since you can define them, you also have the possibility of naming them something more meaningful than Tag.

Sample code for defining an attached property:

```
public static class SomeClass {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TagProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Tag",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(SomeClass),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static object GetTag(DependencyObject dependencyObject) {
        return dependencyObject.GetValue(TagProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTag(DependencyObject dependencyObject, object value) {
        dependencyObject.SetValue(TagProperty, value);
    }

}
```

Usage :

```
<DataGridColumn SomeClass.Tag="abc" />
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Can you provide me an example for using this while generating and reading the column tag property?

Comment: Added sample code. I suggest that you read entirely the link in my original post, it explains the core concept of an attached dependency property and has samples.

Comment: i am trying to add tag property in DataGridColumn, but i am its not working propery could u help me regarding that...

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble trying to apply this to a `RowStyle` of `TargetType="DataGridRow"` - it complains that the `Property` being set to `SomeClass.Tag` is null.