# WPF Datagrid Column - How to attach a tag object programatically?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcolumn

Folks,

I need to add a "tag" property to a programatically created WPF `DataGridColumn`. I saw a nice example at [Tag Property in WPF DataGrid Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535894/tag-property-in-wpf-datagrid-column).

However, this example is using the tag property in a statically defined xaml file. In my case, I need to do something similar dynamically. Can someone please tell me how I can achieve this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tag Property in WPF DataGrid Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535894/tag-property-in-wpf-datagrid-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I figured out what needs to be done.

First, declare a static `DependencyProperty`:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty TagProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
     "Tag",
     typeof(object),
     typeof(DataGridColumn),
     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
```

Now, simply use it to get/set any object.

```
DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn(...)
col.SetValue(TagProperty, myObject);
MyObject o = (MyObject) col.GetValue(TagProperty);
```

Hope you find this useful.

Regards,
Peter